# Converting a byte non-escaped hex string to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm scrapping a website script and I came across a variable
`var string = "\x61\x48\x52\x30\x63\x44\x6f\x76\x4c\x33\x42\x73\x64\x43\x35\x68\x62\x6d\x6c\x74\x5a\x57\x68\x6c\x59\x58\x5a\x6c\x62\x69\x35\x6c\x64\x53\x7c\x72\x63\x33\x6c\x6b\x63\x32\x51\x76\x51\x6c\x38\x74\x58\x31\x52\x6f\x5a\x56\x7c\x43\x5a\x57\x64\x70\x62\x6d\x35\x70\x62\x6d\x63\x74\x4c\x54\x45\x74\x4c\x54\x45\x31\x4d\x6a\x41\x77\x4e\x44\x51\x78\x4d\x7a\x63\x75\x62\x58\x41\x30\x50\x33\x64\x33\x4e\x58\x63\x30\x4d\x51\x3d\x3d"`

it's a part of a long string so I'm storing it in python as a substring variable as follows:

let's say that the div that has the script I need is stored in a `div` variable, therefore `script = div.script.text` returns the script I need, then I search for the above string beginning `st = script.find("var string=")` and the end of this string `end = script.find(";", k)`, now I can form the string using `string = script[st + 11: end - 1]`, now if I run `print(string)` it prints

```
"\x61\x48\x52\x30\x63\x44\x6f\x76\x4c\x33\x42\x73\x64\x43\x35\x68\x62\x6d\x6c\x74\x5a\x57\x68\x6c\x59\x58\x5a\x6c\x62\x69\x35\x6c\x64\x53\x7c\x72\x63\x33\x6c\x6b\x63\x32\x51\x76\x51\x6c\x38\x74\x58\x31\x52\x6f\x5a\x56\x7c\x43\x5a\x57\x64\x70\x62\x6d\x35\x70\x62\x6d\x63\x74\x4c\x54\x45\x74\x4c\x54\x45\x31\x4d\x6a\x41\x77\x4e\x44\x51\x78\x4d\x7a\x63\x75\x62\x58\x41\x30\x50\x33\x64\x33\x4e\x58\x63\x30\x4d\x51\x3d\x3d"
```

but I can't get it's actual value, running python in terminal shows the following results

```
>>> string = "\x61\x48\x52\x30\x63\x44\x6f\x76\x4c\x33\x42\x73\x64\x43\x35\x68\x62\x6d\x6c\x74\x5a\x57\x68\x6c\x59\x58\x5a\x6c\x62\x69\x35\x6c\x64\x53\x7c\x72\x63\x33\x6c\x6b\x63\x32\x51\x76\x51\x6c\x38\x74\x58\x31\x52\x6f\x5a\x56\x7c\x43\x5a\x57\x64\x70\x62\x6d\x35\x70\x62\x6d\x63\x74\x4c\x54\x45\x74\x4c\x54\x45\x31\x4d\x6a\x41\x77\x4e\x44\x51\x78\x4d\x7a\x63\x75\x62\x58\x41\x30\x50\x33\x64\x33\x4e\x58\x63\x30\x4d\x51\x3d\x3d"
>>> string
'aHR0cDovL3BsdC5hbmltZWhlYXZlbi5ldS|rc3lkc2QvQl8tX1RoZV|CZWdpbm5pbmctLTEtLTE1MjAwNDQxMzcubXA0P3d3NXc0MQ=='
```

That `'aHR0cDovL3BsdC5hbmltZWhlYXZlbi5ldS|rc3lkc2QvQl8tX1RoZV|CZWdpbm5pbmctLTEtLTE1MjAwNDQxMzcubXA0P3d3NXc0MQ=='` is what I need, so how to get it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You already have it -- it's right there in `string`. If you're thinking "but it can't be that simple, because I'm passing `string` to some algorithm that expects data in a certain format, and that code is failing, so the data must be in the wrong format", let's see that code too.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're thinking, "yes, I know that `string` contains the data I want, but I can only create `string` by copying the output of my web scraper and pasting it into the terminal. I want to know how to get that data directly inside my web scraper", let's see the code for your web scraper.

Comment: @Kevin your second comment is what I'm aspiring, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution a long time ago and forgot to post the answer, so sorry for those who came across the same problem.

First, we need to escape the hex string by removing the `\x` from it:

```
un_escaped_hex_string = "\x61\x48\x52\..."
escaped_hex_string = un_escaped_hex_string.replace("\\x", "")
```

After removing the `\x` we have generated a hex string, so, to get it's value we do the following:

```
byte_value = bytes.fromhex(escaped_hex_string)
value = byte_value.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded - it has a certain look to it, and the `==` at the end are a dead giveaway. You can use the [`base64` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) to turn it back into a byte string.

```
import base64
base64.b64decode(string)
```

Comment: Doing what you said get me this ```b'\xc7\xadq\xe3\xccy\xdb\x1d\xf4\xc7\xad\xf1\xe3\x8cz\x7f\ x1e\xfa\xc7\x871\xdf|x\xdb\x1e\xf7\xc7\xae1\xe3|w\xe7\x1e\ xbc\xc7\xad\xb1\xe9\xdczs\x1e\xf8\xc7\x96\xb1\xe7\xbcz\xf3 \x1e\x9c\xc7\x9fq\xe7\xccyk\x1e\x9c\xc7\xad\xb1\xeb\xdcw\x e7\x1e\x9c\xc7\xae1\xe7|{s\x1e\xf6\xc7\xad\xf1\xdf|zs\x1e\ x9b\xc7\xad\xf1\xdfly\xd7\x1e\xfa\xc7\x9dq\xe9\xccw\xf3\x1 e\xf8\xc7\x9f1\xdf\\y\xdb\x1e\x9f\xc7\x96\xb1\xe7\xac{s\x1 e7\xc7\x96\xb1\xe7\xbcz\xe3\x1e\xf4\xc7\xad\xb1\xe9\xdcw\x e7\x1e\xf4\xc7\xad\xb1\xe9\xdcz\xdf\x1e\xf8\xc7\x871\xe7\x 8cx\xe7\x1e\xf8\xc7\x871\...```

Comment: @XaydenRosario that's not the same string you used in the question then.

Comment: @XaydenRosario this is why you're asked to provide code in the question. Context is essential.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`, since the Javascript string literal in question is also a valid Python string literal.

```
>>> x = r'"\x61\x48"'
>>> ast.literal_eval(x)
'aH'
```

Comment: It returns `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`